# google appengine sdk:HTTP Exception on localhost; runs perfectly on appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm writing a Google AppEngine python application that needs to connect to Google for authentication. I must have changed something which I've spent the last 5 days trying to figure out: this application previously would run (and perform said authentication) while deployed on localhost but fails to do so now. Once I deploy to appengine however, this error ceases to exist. I have established that it isn't an internet connection issue as I've deployed it on another computer and it still gives me the same error.

Here's what the stack trace is like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\_webapp25.py", line 701, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "C:\Users\username\Desktop\AppEngine Things\engineapp\main.py", line 372, in get
    creds = self.GetCodeCredentials()
  File "C:\Users\username\Desktop\AppEngine Things\engineapp\main.py", line 323, in GetCodeCredentials
    creds = oauth_flow.step2_exchange(code)
  File "lib\oauth2client\client.py", line 883, in step2_exchange
    headers=headers)
  File "lib\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1445, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "lib\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1197, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "lib\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1167, in _conn_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "lib\httplib2\__init__.py", line 999, in getresponse
    raise httplib.HTTPException()
HTTPException
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy now? You can add a print statement in line 999 to see what exception is being raised and start debugging from there.

Comment: I'm not behind a proxy. The exception doesn't have any message attached to it

Comment: Yes, but that exception is triggered by other exception. So if you can log the original one it would point us in the right direction.

Comment: You should really start using a version control system. Then you would know what you changed in your code that stopped working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408450/why-should-i-use-version-control

Comment: @SebastianKreft The code there basically checks for a response and if there isn't a response it throws an HTTPException.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't that line, but just above in the method request. Look for this lines except (DownloadError, ResponseTooLargeError,  SSLCertificateError): raise httplib.HTTPException()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the app via `dev_appserver.py` on the command line seemed to solve the problem. I really don't have much insight into why that is so though. So now I can't use the GUI launcher for the sdk