# How do teams work on VB ASP.NET MVC sites?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

In PHP, you can just log in to the FTP and see all of the files.  I notice in VB ASP.NET MVC when I publish a site it doesn't include the controllers or models.  Rather, it seems to compile them into DLLs.  How can the files be modified with out access to the originals?  Would a developer have to publish the files in a separate directory and then the other developer pull them down and open the project in visual studio?

Comment: It's considered bad practice to make edits directly to deployed files, even if it's a dev environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep your SourceCode in a **Version Control System**  like SVN /GIT /TFS etc.. Whenever you want to make an update , Get the specific version you want to update and make update to that.

Having a Version control gives you so many advantages

**1) Collaborative working**. Many members of a team can work on same code base without overwriting conflict

**2)  Restore to a Previous Version** : Something wrong with the current production move ?. Just get the Previous version (Label) which is working fine (and was running in prod) and rollback to that till you fix the issue.

Keeping the Previous versions of code will save a lot of time in a Programmers / Team's life.

This SO question has good points about [why we should use version control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408450/why-should-i-use-version-control).

**Version control is not only for Teams**. Individual developers can keep their code in Version controls and sleep nicely

Btw, Your MVC project's Model classes and Controllers classes are compiled into the DLL files.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a lot of companies that work with Visual Studio implement Visual Source Safe.

information can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3h0544kx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

otherwise it's pretty much what Shyju said.

Answer (score 0):

In a professional environment, there is a very clear distinction between editing source code, and deploying to production. You seem to make no distinction.

Usually developers make changes under careful control using a source control system like SVN.

Build & deployment is then done separately by a dedicated team member. Developers do not touch the production servers willy-nilly.

> How can the files be modified with out access to the originals?

I don't understand. If you want developers to have full access to the production environment, why not give them full access to the source code as well? In your PHP example this is a given.

Comment: In PHP, there is only one version: the source code.  There is no compiled version.  Working alone, I typically never used version control (never had a need for it).  Shyju offered good insights promoting it's usage.  I see that may be the only option for providing the source code to the rest of a team.

Comment: Compiled vs. uncompiled doesn't matter. It's a question of access to production environment and the deployment process. Also there are lots of versions: every change a developer makes is a revision, and it's important to keep track of revisions using a source control system. @Pluc: It doesn't matter whether it's "scripting" or "programming". It's software development and the concept applies equally.