# How to integrate SVN and what are the benefits

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn

I am new to dot net. Is svn really helpful to developers?  how to integrate the svn with visual studio 2010? Please mention procedure

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408450/why-should-i-use-version-control

Comment: Svn? everyone has an opinion, some will prefer Svn, some Mercurial, some Git, some (God help us) Visual Source Safe. That you should use a **Source Repository** is not up for debate, _which_ source repository will fuel arguments for centuries to come. Is Svn helpful yes, absoutely, but you need to use it correctly. Do regular (automated if possible) checkouts to a location different to where you work to ensure the code in the repository builds & tests run cleanly. This will help ensure the code in the repository is complete & correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is! Is very important to commit your source code in to a source control system like SVN.

For SVN you can use the Visual Studio Plugin ankhsvn it's compatible with 2005, 2008, 2010 and 2012.:

http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/

Below a basic tutorial:

http://www.codetunnel.com/blog/post/92/ankhsvn-basics-tutorial

Comment: This is very helpful link for me thank you Erwin...

Answer (score 2):

Like a free of charge solution would recommend :

[AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/)

From *my* experience point of view I never find myself comfortable with such plugins in VS, as they usually made my VS slower, and I need fast IDE to work.

So *I* always choose simple 
[Tortoise](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) standalone solution.

Comment: @downovter: *any* reason, or downvoting is your hobby ?

Answer (score -1):

There are so many Plugins available for Visual Studio, You can make use of Visual Studio Extension Gallery to explore..

here are some

**Free**
VsTortoise - a TortoiseSVN add-in for Microsoft Visual Studio - http://vstortoise.codeplex.com/
AnkHSVN

**Paid**
Visual SVN

Comment: VisualSVN works on non-domain machines for free.