# Upload to heroku without git

Tags: heroku

Im making a tiny web app, really just for personal testing, the app is built with php / mysql, i plan to host it on heroku, but i was wondering is it possible to host stuff on heroku without pushing from git.

I am not too keen on using git as it's another thing to setup and i don't need any collaborators on this project, also if i want to keep my code private i have to sign-up to a premium account. Both of those seem kind of backwards if all i want to do is upload a project to heroku.

Does any one know a way round this where i can upload a local file directly from the command line ?

Comment: You don't have to use an external service for git per se. And if you do want it, for back-up or collaboration, you could also use Bitbucket. They offer unlimited free private repositories.

Comment: The deployment uses **git**, not **GitHub**.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use a plugin `heroku push` that is built by one of the Heroku engineers. You can find it at https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-push. But there isn't a FTP style upload available if that's what you're looking for.

Also, just because Heroku uses Git doesn't mean you have to have a Github account (since you mention having to have a premium account). All Github provides is an additional place to store your code if you are working on it  in a team. There is absolutely NO REASON that you have to use github to use Heroku.

UPDATE: Heroku recently introduced programmatic builds which let you deploy a TAR file directly to Heroku via their API. Read more at https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/12/20/programmatically_release_code_to_heroku_using_the_platform_api

UPDATE2: Heroku have now introduced HTTP GIT - much simpler without having to deal with SSH keys and such like. Also, DropBox deployment is pretty neat.

Comment: The Project Heroku Push is now deprecated.

Comment: how can i handle .env file? it is taking code from github, i will not push my .env to git

Answer (score 11):

A current option [recommended to replace heroku-push](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-push/issues/15) is [heroku-builds](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-builds).

With it, you can use `heroku builds:create` to deploy the current working directory to a Heroku app, among other things.

Comment: This is super helpful when you have stuff you need uploaded even though it's in your `.gitignore`.

Comment: Can you mention how to upload a folder by this method. Thank you

Comment: @KaranGandhi I'm not sure what you mean. This command uploads the entire folder that it is run inside of, along with all subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-push and push directories without git.

But I think git is better, because you can setup your repository local so your code is privat and source control isn't a worse thing even if you work alone. You may read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408450/why-should-i-use-version-control)