# Beginner in Git, Starting from Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I'm working in a project in Android Studio and up to now, I've copied my files in other directory to change my code for adding new improvements in my program.
And this way is very overwhelming for me.

But I heard that is a good idea use Git when developing, and I want to try it. But I have some questions:

1. My app is not published yet, should I use Git or other VCS?
2. How can I use Git from Android Studio?
3. Is there any risks to my app in development get messed while trying a VCS?

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408450/why-should-i-use-version-control

Comment: @Morrison Thanks for sharing! After reading it, I am realizing now: How could I code without a vcs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- *What is VCS and why should you use it?*

There are many benefits of using a version control system for your projects.

**Collaboration**

Without a VCS in place, you're probably working together in a shared folder on the same set of files.It's extremely error-prone as sooner or later, someone will overwrite someone else's changes.

With a VCS, everybody on the team is able to work absolutely freely - on any file at any time. The VCS will later allow you to merge all the changes into a common version.

**Storing Versions (Properly)**

Saving a version of your project after making changes is an essential habit. But without a VCS, this becomes tedious and confusing very quickly:

**Restoring Previous Versions**

Being able to restore older versions of a file (or even the whole project) effectively means one thing: you can't mess up! If the changes you've made lately prove to be garbage, you can simply undo them in a few clicks. Knowing this should make you a lot more relaxed when working on important bits of a project.

**Understanding What Happened**

Every time you save a new version of your project, your VCS requires you to provide a short description of what was changed. Additionally (if it's a code / text file), you can see what exactly was changed in the file's content. This helps you understand how your project evolved between versions.

**Backup**

A side-effect of using a distributed VCS like Git is that it can act as a backup; every team member has a full-blown version of the project on his disk - including the project's complete history.

- *How to use GIT on Android Studio*

[Have a look here](https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/how-to-use-git-hub-with-android-studio/)

Comment: Thanks for answering! I just installed git on pc and I started usung it. I didn't realize how simple it is!